# trigger to update a different table after update in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I need to write a trigger for my `catalog` table, and its structure can be seen below. [image: Structure of Table Catalog]

Is there a way I can write a trigger so that if an item in the catalog is set from `available` to `backordered`, set the `order` status to `delayed`. Basically you need to update the `order` table after update command in `catalog` table.

Structure of `order` table:

```
phone, aname, config, o_time, quantity, price, status
```

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Could you share any links which will be helpful for my case?

Comment: Open the edit tab for the table. There you'll find a "Triggers" tab which will allow you to select where the trigger should go. Then simply write the trigger. Workbench should get the syntax going for you. Once you have a specific question about writing it they'll be ways to help.

Comment: How are the catalog and order related? How would you go about finding the order with the catalog.

Comment: catalog(`anme, config are the primary key`) , in order table (`aname, config are the foreign key`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a few assumptions here but it shouldn't be too much to adapt it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `catalog_AFTER_UPDATE` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `catalog` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if (old.status = 'available' and new.status = 'backordered') then
        update _order
        set _order.status = 'delayed'
        where _order.aname = old.aname
        and _order.config = old.config;
    end if;
END
```

That should be what you're looking for. `order` is a keyword; not sure that's working for you or not. I obviously used `_order`.

Comment: This much is super helpful :) Thank you

Comment: I really need to learn adding `if` and `else` in my sql statements

Comment: How do you connect `old.status` and `new.status` to `status` column in catalog? or this will automatically take new and old values

Comment: Old and new are catalog tempts. If you update the status of a catalog then the old has its old status and new has the updated one. After you update it the trigger will run and give you old and new.